# NinjectMVC3's WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod assembly attribute causing warnings in my view source editors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ninject.web.mvc, webactivator

When using NinjectMVC3's `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute in my web application,

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
```

I am seeing the following warning in each of my view source editor files:

> xxx.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start
>   initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw
>   an exception with the following error message: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation..   xxx.cshtml 1 1

it manifests itself as a blue-squiggly on the first line of each of my view files (e.g. a `@using` or `@model` declaration). Note that the application runs just fine, the problem is only while editing my view source files (visual studio real-time error / warning analysis).

I can verify that `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` is the cause by commenting it out.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

WebActivator is not a component of Ninject, it's provided by Microsoft, and maintained by David Ebbo, an architect on the MVC team.  Ninject is just using WebActivator to install itself without having to modify global.asax.

Clearly you have some configuration incorrect as this should not be happening.  Are you using some third party editor, like Resharper or CodeRush?

Make sure you have the latest version of WebActivator (use NuGet to update).  Also, are you using any other extensions?

I can't understand how this can affect your design-time view, since this attribute should only take effect when the application is running.  The only thing I can think of is that a third party extension is getting tripped up by parsing the line, and is causing the problem.

Try disabling all extensions and see if the problem remains.

Comment: I had been using a trial version of Resharper but uninstalled it recently (could be a correlation, not positive). Other relevant addins / extensions I have are Chirpy and Web Extensions -- I tried disabling each of those but no change.

Comment: It could be that you didn't uninstall resharper fully.  Try installing it again, and then uninstalling it.  Also, are you using VS SP1?  Are all patches applied?

Comment: Thanks for all of the ideas. I have tried starting Visual Studio in Safe Mode (all plugins disabled) and updating all NuGet packages including WebActivator and the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, VS SP1 with all patches applied. I'll try resinstalling then uninstalling Resharper (if it lets me, my trial has expired by now).

Comment: @StephenSwensen - Well, if all else fails.. uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it (and all updates).  A pain in the butt, but that may be necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time I've resorted to that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this, and just went through this... For me it was because I didn't have a connection string set up. Once I added it, things errors went away.

Comment: Similarly I had a commented out connection string which caused this and also for VS2012 to hang while running a background operation.